# It is possible to insert a record depending on the last record?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I want to register changes of prices in some products, but I would like to not fill the keyspace of duplicate data, that data should only be inserted when the last record is not equal to the new.

This is the definition of the table:

```
create table price_tracker (

    product_id int,
    date timestamp,
    type text,
    price float
    PRIMARY KEY(product_id, date)

) with clustering order by (date desc);
```

Only is I has happened make a search of the last record for this product and compare its price, if not is equal, make an insert.

```
select dateOf(date), type, prie from price_tracker where product_id=1 limit 1;
# If price is not equal to new_price, I insert
insert into price_tracker (product_id, date, type, price) VALUES ( 1, dateof(now()), 'A', **new_price**);
```

But I want to ask if anyone knows any way to make an insert and only proceeds if the value is different, without checking programmatically.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this with 100% correctness. There exists tools like `IF NOT EXISTS` for consistency and `BEGIN BATCH` for atomicity, but they cannot be used together.

You'll have to choose your preferred manner in which it should fail, then programatically make a best attempt to rollback, etc. on any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that C* doesn't support *natively* this access patterns because that would mean locking the records. You have to manually issue a read, do something with your value, and then issue a write. If another client perform the same specific operation then you have a *concurrency* problem. The same problem exist with C* counters, where you can increment/decrement the counter but you can't get its value before/after the update *without* reading the counter, and what you read could already be outdated.

I had a similar use case, and I decided to *cache* things and perform *locks* at application level using a [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) cache to avoid issuing the 
*read* request.

Please also note that if you have *hot* rows you can activate the [row cache](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/maximizing-cache-benefit-with-cassandra) in the YAML configuration file and C* will cache entire rows for you, so your *read* queries will be served from memory and never (well...depends on your data set size) reach disks.

Another approach could be to try to exploit the [Cassandra built-in SSTable compression](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_about_config_compress_c.html) (which should be already enabled by default): for the type of data you're managing in that table you could probably benefits from *always* writing instead of a "read-write if" approach. It depends  on the frequency of your inserts...